# CachedNetworkImage does not show the placeholder when imageUrl dynamically change in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I want the CachedNetworkImage to display placeholder when I change the imageUrl property while it loads the new image, but instead, it is showing the previous image from previous imageUrl.

For example, if I have a setup like this where I have a CachedNetworkImage and a button. When the button is pressed, the state is updated and the imageUrl property of CachedNetworkImage is updated. When this happens, I want the CachedNetworkImage to display placeholder while it loads the new image from the new image Url. How can I achieve what I want?

```
class SampleState extends State<SamplePage> {
  String imageUrl = "https://example.com/someImage.png";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: imageUrl,
          placeholder: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Change image"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              imageUrl = "https://example.com/anotherImage.png";
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force a widget to be completely rebuilt by changing the value of the `key`. For example, you can create a [`ValueKey`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/ValueKey-class.html) from the url String - two keys with the same url are equal.

```
class SampleState extends State<SamplePage> {
  String imageUrl = "https://example.com/someImage.png";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        CachedNetworkImage(
          key: new ValueKey<String>(imageUrl),
          imageUrl: imageUrl,
          placeholder: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Change image"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              imageUrl = "https://example.com/anotherImage.png";
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```